# powershell remove-item windows server 2012 not working

Tags: powershell, cmd, delete-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I have win-server 2012 and my c:\ disk is full.
Ive got a file "win2012r22.iso" 4GB that is old one from 2014 (not in use in any of my hyper-v`s) , and i cannot delete it using powershell as administrator.
Is there another way/command to remove that file so i can free up some space?

```
    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        10/27/2015   7:05 AM            59
d----        10/27/2015   7:04 AM            59free
d----         5/11/2015   6:21 AM            currports
d----         12/9/2014   8:39 AM            ibmmegaraid
d----         12/9/2014   8:32 AM            IBM_Support
d----         7/26/2012  12:21 AM            PerfLogs
d-r--        12/13/2014   1:14 AM            Program Files
d----        12/13/2014   1:14 AM            Program Files (x86)
d-r--         11/7/2012  10:51 AM            Users
d----        10/28/2016   7:51 AM            Windows
-a---        11/10/2012   2:15 AM    5268344 59.exe
-a---        10/27/2015   6:54 AM   37533435 59free.exe
-a---        10/27/2015   7:02 AM   37533435 59free.zip
-a---        10/27/2015   6:59 AM   37533435 59free1.exe
-a---         5/11/2015   6:25 AM   31225832 59manager.exe
-----         11/3/2016   4:50 AM       3456 bootsqm.dat
-a---         8/30/2015  11:04 AM  666894336 centos7min.iso
-a---         11/7/2012  10:55 AM     254328 hvremote.wsf
-a---         12/9/2014   8:31 AM   86051707 ibmmegaraid.exe
-a---         12/9/2014   8:38 AM   85717226 ibmmegaraid.zip
-a---          1/5/2013   8:42 AM    9078784 LinuxICv34.iso
-a---         11/3/2016   6:02 AM          0 Recovery.txt
-a---        11/10/2012  12:28 AM    1622368 vt.exe
-a---         8/30/2015  10:56 AM    1856768 vt32.exe
-a---         1/16/2014  11:41 PM 4268605440 win2012r22.iso


PS C:\> remove-item c:\win2012r22.iso
remove-item : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-item c:\win2012r22.iso
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\win2012r22.iso:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

remove-item : Cannot find path 'C:\win2012r22.iso' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-item c:\win2012r22.iso
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\win2012r22.iso:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but try adding `-Force`.

Comment: @mklement0 same error...

Comment: are you running the powershell under elevated rights?  Right click on powershell and select Run as Administrator.  Normally, users do not have write/delete access to files present at the root of C: drive.

Comment: @Nasir yes i run under "Administrator: Windows PowerShell"
i dont have desktop on that server, only "run task command" that run everything as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the following things:

- Double-check that the ISO isn't attached to some VM.
- Make sure the file isn't in use elsewhere. You can use tools like [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) to check for open handles on a file.
- Can you delete it via the GUI?
- Can you delete it via CMD with the [`del`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771049.aspx) command?